# SQL Update column from one table to another

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm a beginner in SQL however I have two tables one LibraryTable where I have list of songs, and another table called Playlist, I'm using netbeans to program a prototype jukebox, and I can add songs from the Library to my playlist, and I can increment playcount of all the song that where added to the playlist, however both LibraryTable and Playlist have a column called playcount, I want know how I would go about updating the playcount column in LibraryTable with the the playcount column in my Playlist table.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? And what have you tried so far? Please share some code.

Comment: update LibraryTable set playcount =p.playcount  from LibraryTable LT inner join Playlist P on lt.id=p.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do joins in `UPDATE` statements.

```
UPDATE L
SET L.Playcount = P.Playcount
FROM Playlist P
INNER JOIN LibraryTable L
ON P.SongID = L.SongID
```

Comment: You are brilliant thank you worked perfectly, except i just had to change SongID to just ID lol, but thanks for everyones help.